# How to do integration testing on Spring Boot with fake GCS Bucket?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-storage, integration-testing

I have an application that connect to GCS Bucket with Spring Boot. I want to do an integration test with fake gcs server here: https://github.com/fsouza/fake-gcs-server . But I'm very clueless how to do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/), which allows you to spin up infrastructure needed for tests (things like databases, or in your case a fake gcs server)

Start by adding the necessary maven dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <testcontainers.version>1.16.4</testcontainers.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then use the GenericContainer to create a GCS container, specifying the docker image name and version:

```
@Testcontainers
class GcsIntegrationTest {

    // will be shared between test methods
    @Container
    private static final GenericContainer<?> GCS_CONTAINER = new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("fsouza/fake-gcs-server:1.33.1"))
        .withExposedPorts(4443)
        .withClasspathResourceMapping("gcs/data", "/data", BindMode.READ_ONLY)

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertTrue(GCS_CONTAINER.isRunning());
        // more assertions
    }
}
```

The 'withClasspathResourceMapping' part can be used to specify some test data you wish to mount inside the container for the test: https://github.com/fsouza/fake-gcs-server#preload-data